# Is there a tighter upper bound for $\sum_{k=1}^n|k\sin k|$ than $\frac12n(n+1)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Consider the sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^n|k\sin k|$$
An obvious upper bound for this is clearly $\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac12n(n+1)$. But it seems that this upper bound is too "loose", and so I was wondering if it is possible to find a tighter upper bound for it?

Below please find a Mathematica plot for the sum in the interval $n\le1000$.

[image]

Comment: Not sure you can, $\sin k$ is a very capricious sequence. Good question by the way.

Comment: It would improve the Question if you articulated a purpose for the bound to be tighter than $\binom{n+1}{2}$

Comment: I missread your comment sorry. Sure providing motivation for asking a question is somewhat important, but does that really matter ? I never see people wanting question to be motivated here, even if I agree that it is a good thing to be able to do so. But "out of curiosity" seems already to be a good enough reason, to me. @hardmath

Comment: In numerical analysis we are frequently happy with a bound that is within some constant multiple of the actual quantity (calling such bounds "quasi-optimal").  Jyrki's graph suggests the bound in hand is quasi-optimal in that sense.  So I'm trying to gauge if the notion of "looseness" here can be clarified, relative to an application of the bound.

Comment: I see your point. It was not clear to me with your first comment. I agree with you then.

Comment: FWIW, within the resolution of my laptop screen that plot follows the averaging estimate $n(n+1)/\pi$ very closely. There is no visible fluctuation in that scale. The more interesting question might be to derive upper bounds for the error $|f(n)-n(n+1)/\pi|$.

Comment: You can't get another order of magnitude, because $$\sum^n_{k=1}|k\sin k|\ge\sum^n_{k=1}k\sin^2 k=\frac{n(n+1)}4-\frac12\sum^n_{k=1}k\cos 2k,$$ and the sum on the RHS is easily shown to be $O(n).$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The average value of $\left|\sin k\right|$ is $2/\pi$ so an upper bound is probably near $$\frac{n(n+1)}{\pi}$$

As the plot below shows, this is quite accurate when $900\le n\le1000$. $n(n+1)/\pi$ is the red curve, the scatterplot im blue represents the actual sums.

[image]

At most one in every three of $|\sin k|$ is more than $\cos 0.5$ so one bound is near $$\frac{1+2\cos0.5 }6n(n+1)$$

In the same way, the average of $22$ consecutive values of $|\sin k|$ is always between $0.635$ and $0.638$.  So the sum is bounded above by
$$\sum_{k=1}^N k\left|\sin k\right|\lt 0.638\sum_{k=1}^N \left(N-22\lfloor (N-k)/22 \rfloor\right)$$
where each $k$ has been rounded up to the nearest number of the form $N-22m$.
This has a polynomial sum if $N$ is a multiple of $22$, and a finite correction if not.
$$\sum_{k=1}^N k\left|\sin k\right|\lt 0.638\frac{N(N+22)}2+C$$
By noting that $\sum_{k=1}^{22}k|\sin(M+k)|$ is always between $153$ and $169$, this can be improved to
$$0.3175N(N-0.1)+C_1\lt\sum_{k=1}^N k\left|\sin k\right|\lt0.319N(N+2)+C_2$$

Comment: I was just about to comment that the plot supports the estimate that the average of $|\sin k|$ is $2/\pi$.

Comment: Well this is the easy "answer".